# After installing NumPy in Python - I still get error: "no module named numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

I need to install and use the Python NumPy module (and then later the Pandas module) in order to process heavy data in Python.

I downloaded and installed ENTHOUGHT, but it wasn't what I wanted all that extra clutter of extra modules (which defeats the purpose of importing Python modules only as needed), but the uninstall did not work properly (i.e. it left garbage folders and ENTHOUGHT remnants all over my computer).

I have tried installing NumPy via EASY_INSTALL and PIP (two package managers if I understand correctly) - but with no success.  Every time I try to run my program, I get the error:  "no module named numpy".

I have searched the questions here and have tried to alter my ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE as per the following video, but again, no success:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4

```
C:\Python34
```

...still the same error!

I downloaded Anaconda (with all its extra clutter and installed, but I don't like the development environment - I want my Vanilla Python IDLE to run Vanilla NumPy with no extra clutter modules...) and when I tried to again install Numpy  I received a message that it was already installed with a path to:

```
C:\users\yoni\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

....so I ALSO added this PYTHONPATH to the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE in hopes that it would now recognize where the NumPy installation was (currently with Anaconda3 - but I hoped to be able to import NumPy to my vanilla Python IDLE):

```
C:\Python34;C:\users\yoni\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

I don't find a clear answer - I see others have the same problem, and nothing is working for me.  How can I finish this installation of NumPy so that it works for me when I do a simple import of module?

Comment: What OS you use, which python version? In case you use windows, the compiled packages are here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Did you try to copy-paste NumPy folders in to Python path?

Comment: @Marcin I don't trust third-party packages that are not downloaded from the official Python site.  I use Windows 7.  sacma I just made an edit to the question with the paths I used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution until you can resolve your path issue.
It will be environment specific. 
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\users\yoni\anaconda3\lib\site-packages[PackageName]')
import PakcageName

Comment: The solution you offer produces a unicode error saying "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated uXXXX escape" - and this was produced from the following code as per your suggestion:  "import sys
sys.path.append('C:\users\yoni\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy')"